# Chrome - Memory isn't cleared on page reload. What does the reload button actually do?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, page-refresh

My web-app (built with lit-element) became slower with each page reload. Started to look for a leak, which appears to be caused by an element that I initialised via a class field like:

```
export class SearchAutocomplete extends LitElement {

 searchInput: TextInput = new TextInput();

 ...

}
```

After I remove that line, GC kicks in just fine.

However, this makes me wondering why the above line prevented the *tree* to become garbage collected?

More over, why memory is still bound to window after reloading the page, shouldn't that be wiped out immediately?

What does actually happen when we reload/hard reload the page, is that juts equivalent to `location.reload()`?

Thanks!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096907/do-browsers-parse-javascript-on-every-page-load/9261355#9261355

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks, that explains a lot of questions!

Comment: you can do your garbage stuff, just before the user leave with:
```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
      ...
 })
```

Comment: I use this solution to destroy a webworker which wasn't destroy on page reload