# eval (T) vs x = new Function (T); x()

Tags: javascript, security

Mozilla says `eval (T)` is dangerous.
how is `x = new Function(T);x()` less dangerous?
I effectively used AJAX to pass some code for JAVASCRIPT to execute
The `eval (T)` seemed not to work, so I switched code (actually bad code was passed)

Not relevant here but finally did `alert('code='+T)` to help find problem

However, if wanted to make a little safer, I suppose I could add:

```
  T_safer="try{"+T+"}catch (e){alert(e.message+\n code="+T+")}"
  eval (T_safer)  ..... or x =  new Function(T_safer);x()
```

Comment: Why do you think `x = new Function(T);x();` is less dangerous?

"Calling the `Function` constructor directly can create functions dynamically, but **suffers from security** and similar (but far less significant) performance **issues to `eval`.**" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: Your "safer" version adds no safety.

Answer (score 2):

## It's not.

`eval` and `new Function` are just about equally dangerous.

To understand the security flaw caused by `eval` and `new Function`, read [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86513/3140).

The basic issue is that, when evaluating a string provided by someone else, you can't trust that user to always act appropriately. This is called an **injection attack**. The attacker can trick your page into doing just about anything they want.

Even if you wrote the code to be executed, you still shouldn't use a `String`, either. In almost every case, you can use a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_expressions) to pass a `Function` instead of a `String`. This is very likely to perform faster, as well as being more readable because it *looks like code* instead of a string. Compare the formatting on the following definitions:

```
T1 = new Function('a', 'b', 'alert("hi");return a + b');
T2 = function(a, b) { alert("hi");return a + b }
```

See how the second one has all of the tokens inside the function body highlighted correctly? That's a sign things are going well.

---

## What are you trying to do?

> I effectively used AJAX to pass some code for JAVASCRIPT to execute

There's a better way to get the browser to execute some trusted code from a server: a `<script src=...>` element. You can add these dynamically. Then you don't have to load a (potentially enormous) `String` payload and pass it through the `eval` pipeline, and your browser can start doing smart things [code caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9261355/3140).

---

## What's the nuance between `eval` and `new Function`?

In terms of security, `eval` and `new Function` have the **same flaw**. The only difference is that code in a `new Function` does not form a closure over your local scope, so there is a *very puny* increase in security by preventing the injected code from accessing your local variables. But that's really not worth much at all.